# HTML tags inside APEX_ITEM.DISPLAY_AND_SAVE

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

APEX version 4.0

I need to display dynamic content on APEX form. Region based on query like this:

```
SELECT DECODE(my_table.field_type, 
              'WRITE', APEX_ITEM.text(3, my_table.field_value, 100), 
              'READ', APEX_ITEM.DISPLAY_AND_SAVE(3, some_func_ret_html(my_table.field_value)))
  FROM my_table
```

Unfortunatelly instead of formatted html text all I can see:

```
some text... <a href="#" onClick="window.open('f?p=100:3211:1054743242911795::NO::P3211_RREF_ID,P3211_COLUMN_NAME,P3211_ID:-1,AWPST_FIELD_VALUE_CLOB,3', '_blank', 'height=700,width=800,alwaysRaised=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')">link_name</a>
```

Column property "Display As" set to "Standart Report Column".

Comment: It should work as you expected ,You can check whether HTML return by function some_func_ret_html() is correct or not.

Comment: That's expected since you've wrapped your HTML in a call to `APEX_ITEM.DISPLAY_AND_SAVE`. Why do you need to call APEX_ITEM there anyway if your function is already returning the HTML you want?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Yes, maybe I don't need apex_Item for read-only element at all. I think it's better way to solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change page source/ region source to pl/sql block and pass this code in HTP. format this might work.